# How to identify why rows are duplicating

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The below query selects all the rows from a master table (there are no duplicates in the table i have checked) and this query counts the number of business days and checks it against a certain number of days, if the count is greater than that certain number of days, it is late, else it is not late.  For some reason when I run this query, even with the select DISTINCT, my rows are duplicating. I see a row for each tracking number showing one as Late and the other as Not Late but I don't see how they could possibly be showing both answers?  Could anyone help me understand why my rows are being duplicated?

```
SELECT DISTINCT case UT.[Service] when '0PW' then 'UPS SurePost 1 lb or Greater' else UT.[Service] end as 'Service'
        ,US.[Region]
        ,UT.[Tracking_Number]  as 'TrackingCounts'
        ,UT.Manifest_Date
        ,UT.Date_Delivered
        ,Ship_To_Postal_Code
        ,WarehouseLocation
        ,CASE 
                    WHEN UT.[Service] = 'UPS Ground' AND WarehouseLocation = 'Wausau' then iif(((
                          DATEDIFF(dd, UT.[Manifest_Date], CASE WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] = '1/1/2099') THEN GETDATE() WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] IS NULL) THEN GETDATE() ELSE UT.[DATE_DELIVERED] END) )
                        -(DATEDIFF(wk, UT.[Manifest_Date], CASE WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] = '1/1/2099') THEN GETDATE() WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] IS NULL) THEN GETDATE() ELSE UT.[DATE_DELIVERED] END) * 2)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, UT.[Manifest_Date]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, UT.[Date_Delivered]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(Select Count(*) from [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_HolidayDates] where  [HolidayDate] between UT.[Manifest_Date] and UT.[Date_Delivered])) > UZ.TNTDAYS, 1, 0)
                    WHEN UT.[Service] in ('UPS SurePost 1 lb or Greater','UPS SurePost Less than 1 lb','0PW') AND WarehouseLocation = 'Wausau' then iif(((
                          DATEDIFF(dd, UT.[Manifest_Date], CASE WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] = '1/1/2099') THEN GETDATE() WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] IS NULL) THEN GETDATE() ELSE UT.[DATE_DELIVERED] END) )
                        -(DATEDIFF(wk, UT.[Manifest_Date], CASE WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] = '1/1/2099') THEN GETDATE() WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] IS NULL) THEN GETDATE() ELSE UT.[DATE_DELIVERED] END) * 2)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, UT.[Manifest_Date]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, UT.[Date_Delivered]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(Select Count(*) from [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_HolidayDates] where  [HolidayDate] between UT.[Manifest_Date] and UT.[Date_Delivered])) > (UZ.TNTDAYS + 1), 1, 0)
                    ELSE iif(((
                          DATEDIFF(dd, UT.[Manifest_Date], CASE WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] = '1/1/2099') THEN GETDATE() WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] IS NULL) THEN GETDATE() ELSE UT.[DATE_DELIVERED] END))
                        -(DATEDIFF(wk, UT.[Manifest_Date], CASE WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] = '1/1/2099') THEN GETDATE() WHEN (UT.[Date_Delivered] IS NULL) THEN GETDATE() ELSE UT.[DATE_DELIVERED] END) * 2)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, UT.[Manifest_Date]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, UT.[Date_Delivered]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(Select Count(*) from [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_HolidayDates] where  [HolidayDate] between UT.[Manifest_Date] and UT.[Date_Delivered])) > USS.[Days], 1, 0)   
            End as LATE
  FROM [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_UPS_Automation_QVM_Tracking] UT
  INNER JOIN [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_UPS_Automation_States] US on US.[State] = UT.[Ship_To_State_Province]
  INNER JOIN [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_UPS_Automation_Ground_Zips] UZ on UZ.[DESTZIPCODE] = UT.[Ship_To_Postal_Code]
  INNER JOIN [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_UPS_Automation_Services] USS on UT.[Service] = UT.[Service]
  where cast(UT.Manifest_Date as date) between '1/20/2019' and '1/26/2019' AND WarehouseLocation = 'Wausau' and UT.Status = 'Delivered'
  group by UT.[Service],US.[Region], USS.Days, UT.[Manifest_Date], UT.[Date_Delivered], TNTDAYS, Tracking_Number, Ship_To_Postal_Code, WarehouseLocation
```

So I found the issue is on `INNER JOIN [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_UPS_Automation_Services] USS on UT.[Service] = UT.[Service]`

however I don't understand why when i join  `UT.SERVICE` on `USS.Service` the uss.service field shows every possible service, and not the value that `Ut.SERVICE` has.

if `UT.Service` = `UPS 2nd Day Air` wouldn't the join on USS only give me UPS 2nd Day Air values?

Comment: You get a duplicate if any of your joins result in more than one row.

Comment: I found the join where the issue is, thank you for pointing that out, I am a little confused still though.

Comment: If your table relationships are 1:N then when you do an INNER JOIN between those tables you will get N rows, not 1 row. To answer your question, you never filtered UT.Service from the JOIN or WHERE, so no you won't get just those values, you'll just get NULLS or empty data from that CASE statement. A common fix is to join to a subquery where you select a MAX or use DISTINCT so you get a single row.

Comment: Can't help you further without seeing the actual data.

Comment: `Table B` only has two fields, a Service, and a count of days. I don't think this is one to many right?

Comment: The number of columns does not represent the relationship type. Do you have a typo? INNER JOIN [Reporting_Operations].[CORP\u694172].[tbl_UPS_Automation_Services] USS on **UT.[Service] = UT.[Service]**

Comment: Im super embarassed I actually just caught this error before you typed that out.. It looks like that was the problem. I will accept the answer below as it answered my question as to how I can single out which rows are duplicates. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is one of the joins returns more than 1 records
The way you need to find the the root cause of issue is:

1- Remove all columns from your select to become `Select * from yourtable`

2- comment all joins

3- uncomment joins and watch your data to see if the become duplicate

3.1- if the records are not duplicated that join is OK, do the same on next join

3.2- if records get duplicated, means join might not be right, usually some join conditions are missing

4- After fixing the join issue, remove * and bring back the fields

5- do final check